# Discarding Returned Variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am only interested in one of the things returned by a Python method. I recall reading that there is a convention for how to indicate throw-away variables, but now I can't find any reference to it. Basically, I want to do the following:

`-, var, - = three_things()`

where `three_things()` returns a list of three objects, and var gets the only one of them that I want to keep. What is the "right" way to indicate throw-away variables?

Comment: `_, var, _ = three_things()`

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is to give throwaways the name `_`.

```
>>> _, x, _ = [1,2,3]
>>> x
2
```

(Somewhat) more realistic example:

```
>>> lst = [(1,2,'a'), (3,4,'b')]
>>> for num1, num2, _ in lst:
...     num1 + num2
... 
3
7
```

(In an interactive interpreter session, `_` also stores the last eval'd value.)